# Ubuntu doesn't recognize changes on Android internal storage

Tags: ubuntu, usb, android, mtp, gvfs

I connect my "Onyx Boox Max Lumi 2" e-reader (Android 11) to my "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS" notebook by a USB-cable.

Then I use the Onyx reader to edit a PDF file stored in the Android Internal Storage.
In "Total Commander for Android" I see that size and modification date of the changed file is updated. It's ok.

However, the Linux terminal shows the same file unchanged (`ls --full-time`). To update information in the terminal I have to disconnect the USB-cable and connect it back. After this reconnect `ls` shows correct file size and modification date.
I double checked `ls` output with standard Ubuntu "Files" application, it's the same.

Why `ls` can't recognize changes in the Android file system?
How to force `ls` to recognize changes automatically?
(I need this for PDF library sync between the notebook and the reader)

Thank you!

Comment: MTP is a pretty slow protocol, so I would expect Linux to cache data on PC side. What package do you use for accessing MTP in terminal, ´gvfs´?

Comment: @Robert, Yes, it's `gvfs`, because I can see `gvfs` in the terminal path `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=QUALCOMM_BENGAL-IDP__SN%3A6218B8FC_1B5B21A9/Internal shared storage/Books`. This package was used by Ubuntu by default (I just plugged USB in)